# Reducir el espacio virtual de un disco de proxmox

Tags: proxmox

Tengo un disco vm en proxmox de 70GB que necesito que se reduzca a 55GB.
La máquina que lo tiene es un Windows11 que ya he reducido a 53GB

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde la memoria me da, lo que se hace equivale a clonarlo en un nuevo disco más pequeño usando `qemu-img`. Algo como

```
qemu-img resize -f raw /ruta/a/eldisco.raw 55G
```

Luego actualizas el archivo  `lxc/$vmid.conf` con la nueva info del disco.

Ahora, viendo en [la documentación](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Resize_disks), hay otras opciones. Aunque, de nuevo, comentan en perfecto inglés que

> Si reduce el disco duro, claramente remover (una sección del disco) probablemente va a destruir su sistema de archivos y borrará los datos en él! En este caso es esencial actuar en la VM en principio, reduciendo el sistema de archivos y el tamaño de la partición. Un SystemRescueCD se hace útil en este caso, añadiendo su ISO en la unidad de CDROM en la VM y cambiando la prioridad de arranque para iniciar desde CD.
>
> Encoger discos no está soportado por la PVE API y debe hacerse manualmente.

Por lo tanto, ES MUY IMPORTANTE que hagas un backup y todo lo demás porque, si lo que dices que redujiste a 53GB no es cierto, va a fallar.

*Lo otro: dejar 2GB de crecimiento no es muy poco? Eso hace fallar la mayoría de actualizaciones de calidad de Windows por falta de espacio.*